# presentation of numeric in different format of multiple rows in SAS

Tags: sas

I want to present the rows of the same column in different format.

my dataset looks like

```
variable1 variable2     variable3
subj1       6.458         5.765
subj2       4.678         20.89
subj3         ...           ....
mean        4.879         5.156
cv          10.167        9.89
sd          10.456        10.007
```

and this that I want is

```
variable1    variable2     variable3
    subj1       6.458         5.765
    subj2       4.678         20.89
    subj3         ...           ....
    mean        4.879         5.16
    cv          10.2           9.9
    sd          10.4          10.01
```

Could someone help me? Thank you!

Comment: I don't think you can have multiple formats for a single variable. You could probably cheat and make it look like they are, but why would you want to do that?

Comment: Is this for a REPORT?  Did you try using PROC REPORT?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have multiple formats in a single column, but you can conditionally round.

```
data want;
    set have;

    if(variable1 in('cv', 'sd') ) then do;
        variable2 = round(variable2, 0.1);
        variable3 = round(variable3, 0.1);
    end;
run;
```